# Задача со сходящимся рядом

Tags: java

Задача 5.38 из сборника Златопольского.

Некий мужчина отправляется на работу, которая находится на расстоянии 1 км от дома. Дойдя до места работы, он вдруг вспоминает, что перед уходом забыл поцеловать жену, и поворачивает назад. Пройдя
полпути, он меняет решение, посчитав, что правильнее вернуться на работу.
Пройдя 1/3 км по направлению к работе, он вдруг осознает, что будет на-
стоящим подлецом, если так и не поцелует жену. На этот раз, прежде чем изменить мнение, он проходит 1/4 км. Так он продолжает метаться, и после N-
этапа, пройдя 1/N км, снова меняет решение.

Определить:
а) на каком расстоянии от дома будет находиться мужчина после 100-го этапа
(если допустить, что такое возможно);

б) какой общий путь он при этом пройдет.
Обработка

Мое решение:

```java
    public class TaskCh05N038 {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int turn;

            // задание стартовых позиций пути и расстояния

            float way = 0;
            float distance = 0;

            // Цикл в 100 поворотов

            for (turn = 1; turn < 101; turn++) {

                // Проверка текущего действия, т.е. четное/нечетное направление движения

                if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                    way = way - (1 / turn);
                    distance = distance + (1 / turn);
                } else if (turn % 2 != 0) {
                    distance = distance + (1 / turn);
                    way = way + (1 / turn);
                }

                System.out.println("Путь = " + way);
                System.out.println("Расстояние = " + distance);
            }
        }
    }
```

Логика в задаче проста и понятна. В обоих случаях это сходящийся ряд. Но в ответ я в обоих случаях получаю 1(а этого быть не должно, путь < расстояния). В конечном счете путь<1, расстояние>1.
Где моя ошибка?

Comment: Во-первых \sum 1/n всё таки расходится, хотя тут это неважно. Во вторых, 1/turn всегда 0, т.к. деление целочисленное.  надо 1./turn

Comment: В третьих, такие вещи считают с конца (от 100 к 1), что бы уменьшить ошибки округления

Answer (score 1):

У вас целочисленное деление. Исправьте `1 / turn` на `1.0 / turn`.

Странно, что это не просилось в глаза, вы же на каждой итерации выводите результаты.

*Еще можно расчёт дистанции вынести из if..else, так как он одинаковый в обоих случаях. Да и if после else убрать, так как эта проверка лишняя.*

Comment: Я только учусь. Пока мне такое в глаза не бросается.

Comment: @Eugene ну вы же видите, что результаты не изменяются. Это, кстати, полезный навык - выводить промежуточные значения на печать, если что-то происходит не так, как планировалось.

Comment: Я и выводил. Я просто не учел, что 1 и 1. различные числа. Не подумал о типе результата деления. Учту на будущее.